# Zookeeper 3.4.9 : ant rpm target failing

Tags: ant, redhat, apache-zookeeper, rpm

I am trying to create zookeeper 3.4.9 rpm.

I have downloaded the 3.4.9 release from git and trying to run the ant build.
However the ant build is failing with the below error:

```
      ..
      ..
      ..
      [rpm] -rwxr-xr-x 0/0            3817 2016-11-10 15:45 zookeeper-3.4.9/src/packages/update-zookeeper-env.sh
      [rpm] -rwxr-xr-x 0/0            1771 2016-11-10 15:45 zookeeper-3.4.9/src/recipes/lock/src/c/tests/zkServer.sh
      [rpm] -rwxr-xr-x 0/0            1771 2016-11-10 15:45 zookeeper-3.4.9/src/recipes/queue/src/c/tests/zkServer.sh
      [rpm] Executing(%build): /bin/bash -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.DnyC6m
      [rpm] Executing(%install): /bin/bash -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.h96FLJ
      [rpm] + STATUS=0
      [rpm] + '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
      [rpm] + /usr/bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
      [rpm] + exit 0
      [rpm] + umask 022
      [rpm] + cd /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD
      [rpm] + cd zookeeper-3.4.9
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/usr
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/usr/bin
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/usr/include
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/usr/lib
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/usr/lib64
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/usr/libexec
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/var/log/zookeeper
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/etc/zookeeper
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/usr/man
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/var/run/zookeeper
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/usr/sbin
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/usr/share/zookeeper
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/var/lib/zookeeper
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/etc/init.d
      [rpm] + cp /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/zookeeper-3.4.9/src/packages/rpm/init.d/zookeeper /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/etc/init.d/zookeep
      [rpm] + cp /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/zookeeper-3.4.9/src/packages/update-zookeeper-env.sh /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/zookeeper-3.4.9
      [rpm] + chmod 0755 /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/zookeeper-3.4.9/sbin/update-zookeeper-env.sh /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/zookeeper-3.4.9build_root/BUILD/zookeeper-3.4.9/sbin/zkServer.sh
      [rpm] + chmod 0755 /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD/etc/init.d/zookeeper
      [rpm] + exit 0
      [rpm] + umask 022
      [rpm] + cd /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD
      [rpm] + '[' /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD '!=' / ']'
      [rpm] + rm -rf /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD
      [rpm]
      [rpm]
      [rpm] RPM build errors:
      [rpm] ++ dirname /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD
      [rpm] + mkdir -p /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root
      [rpm] + mkdir /tmp/zookeeper_package_build_root/BUILD
      [rpm] + cd zookeeper-3.4.9
      [rpm] /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.h96FLJ: line 32: cd: zookeeper-3.4.9: No such file or directory
      [rpm] error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.h96FLJ (%install)
      [rpm]     Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.h96FLJ (%install)
```

I tried :

1) ant rpm -Dskip.contrib=1

2) ant rpm

but both are failing with same error.